# Remove segment from URL

Tags: segments, url

I'd like to take any URL where `segment_1 == "supernav"` and remove that segment. So this:

`http://alpha.ced.berkeley.edu/supernav/gallery/`

Would become this:

`http://alpha.ced.berkeley.edu/gallery/`

How can I do this?

Comment: Are you trying to simply hide the segment from your template, or redirect users from one URL to another?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd create a template group called **supernav**, and put this in its **index** template:

`{redirect="{segment_2}/{segment_3}"}`

(If there's no 3rd segment present, EE will ignore it.)

Comment: Tricky part is I'm using Structure, so templates are quite used the same way...

Answer (score 1):

If you're not actually talking about doing a redirect (it's not quite clear from your question for me) then you may want to consider using Freebie for this:

http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/freebie

In the freebie extension settings you can set supernav to be ignored so, any time you hit `http://alpha.ced.berkeley.edu/gallery/` you are really hitting `http://alpha.ced.berkeley.edu/supernav/gallery/`

And of course you would make sure in your hrefs that you removed `supernav/`.

Comment: I've tried Freebie and I can never seem to get it to work correctly. Not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple mod_rewrite options to try in your .htaccess file to remove the "supernav" segment of your URL:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^supernav/gallery/$ /gallery [L]
```

or

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ supernav/$1 [L]
```

---

Worth taking a look at...

- [mod_rewrite Cheat Sheet](http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/mod-rewrite/)
- [Docs for Apache Module mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)